# How long would it take to compose every tweet possible?

Tags: combinatorics

Assume that the number of distinct characters available to compose each tweet is $c$, the maximum length of a tweet is $l$, the number of people composing tweets simultaneously is $p$, and that the time that it takes to compose a tweet is always $t$ seconds.

There are $c^{l}$ distinct tweets that can be composed, therefore, it would take $\frac{c^{l}}{t}$ seconds, in total, to compose every one of them. However, since there are $p$ people to help do this, assuming also that they always compose distinct tweets, then, it would take $\frac{c^{l}}{pt}$ seconds in total.

Is this correct?

Comment: Unless we require that all tweets have maximal length, the total number of possible tweets is $c + c^2 + \cdots + c^l$, though even for modest $c$ the term $c^l$ dominates by a wide margin.

Comment: There is also a section on this in the book "What if?" by the creator of xkcd

Comment: If tweets are always 140 characters or less and that we restrict characters to say 30 (lowercase alphabet and a few more), we have roughly $30^{140}$ possibilities. But almost all of these will be gibberish. Say there are $10^6$ available words and a tweet will be made up of 5 or less plus a few connecting words so that it makes sense. Then we might have $10^{30}$ possibilities. So if 6 billion people do nothing else but send one per second, they manage about $6\cdot10^9\cdot3\cdot10^7\approx10^{17}$ a year. Expectations for the life of the universe tend to be $10^{9}$ to $10^{10}$ years.